# How to find out which columns are duplicated?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I suspect some of the columns may be duplicates of each other. How can I find out which ones they are? For example:

```
Name          val1       val2     val3     val4

dog            4          0        2        4     
fish           0          0        8        0
falcon         2          2        10       2
falcon         2          2        10       2
fish           0          0        8        0
dog            4          0        2        4
fish           0          0        8        0
dog            4          0        2        4
```

I would like know that val4 and val1 are the same as each other.  My dataframe has about 30 columns. In the end I just want to keep one copy of each duplicate but I do want to know which columns are being dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check duplicated on transpose:

```
df.T.duplicated(keep=False)
```

Output:

```
Name    False
val1     True
val2    False
val3    False
val4     True
dtype: bool
```

And you can drop duplicated with `loc`:

```
df.loc[:,~df.T.duplicated()]
```

Output:

```
     Name  val1  val2  val3
0     dog     4     0     2
1    fish     0     0     8
2  falcon     2     2    10
3  falcon     2     2    10
4    fish     0     0     8
5     dog     4     0     2
6    fish     0     0     8
7     dog     4     0     2
```

---

**Update**: To identify and group duplicated columns, we can do a groupby:

```
df.T.groupby(list(df.index)).ngroup().sort_values()
```

Output:

```
val2    0
val3    1
val1    2
val4    2
Name    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can you explain why column `val1` doesn't also get dropped in your example?

Comment: @shmulvad that's because I used `keep=False` to tag **all** the duplicates. In the second line of code, we don't use `keep=False`, then it keeps the first occurrence as non-duplicate.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to group the duplicated columns together so you can see which are duplicates of which? In this case we can see val1 is a duplicate of val4 easily but if we have more duplicated columns we won't know which are duplicates of which.

Comment: The groupby gives me: ValueError: Grouper for '2020-02-15 00:00:00' not 1-dimensional. df.index is DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-15', '2020-02-16', '2020-02-17', '2020-02-18',
               '2020-02-19', '2020-02-20', '2020-02-21', '2020-02-22',
               '2020-02-23', '2020-02-24',
               ...
               '2020-05-24', '2020-05-25', '2020-05-26', '2020-05-27',
               '2020-05-28', '2020-05-29', '2020-05-30', '2020-05-31',
               '2020-06-01', '2020-06-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Time (CET)', length=218, freq=None)